# "Nor does" to start a sentence

Tags: grammar

I don’t understand the meaning of nor does when a sentence starts with.

For example:

> Moscow Police Department said some of the victims had defensive
> wounds, adding that there were no signs of sexual assault, the
> Associated Press reports.
>
> Nor does anything appear to have been stolen from the victims or the
> house, CBS News reports, and there was no sign of forced entry.

[BBC](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-63689176) source

Comment: **It refers to the previous sentence**.

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Are you confused about a conjunction starting a sentence, or you don't know what it's conjoining with or why?

Answer (score 1):

Since coordinating conjunctions are used with independent clauses, you can definitely start a sentence with one. Even though it is often seen as informal, it is still grammatically correct. Here are examples from [MLA Style Center](https://style.mla.org/conjunction-at-start-of-sentence/):

> He started a sentence with a coordinating conjunction. And that was the end of him.

> He started a sentence with a coordinating conjunction. But his wife didn’t leave him.

> He started a sentence with a coordinating conjunction. Or perhaps he only dreamed that he did, because the kale was spoiled.

These are all perfectly grammatical and very common. As you may have noticed, the conjunctions still serve the same purpose, which is logically connecting clauses, except that they aren't joining them now. Therefore, just as how the sentences, "I have written a sentence to demonstrate a grammatical concept. And I have run out of ideas," rely on the conjunction "and" to be logically connected, your sentence, "Nor does anything appear to have been stolen from the victims or the house, CBS News reports, and there was no sign of forced entry," must have one before it, which is the other part of the "nor" statement.

"Neither [this], nor [that]" is now "[the first sentence]. Nor [the second]." Note that for this to work, the first sentence must contain a negative, to which the "nor" clause adds.

Comment: Alright, with the newly posted first sentence, I will apply my explanation.

This can be re-written as "Neither were there signs of sexual assault, nor does anything appear to have been stolen from the victims or the house."

Comment: *There were no signs of sexual assault. Nor does anything appear to have been stolen, either.*

Comment: @tchrist That's definitely better. Thanks.